# Change background when active class changes on Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, containers, carousel

I wanted to change the background of a container every time the slider slides. I figure I need to check if/ when the class of the item because active. I also wonder if there isn't an event for which I should be listening. Here's the jsfiddle I'm working on:

https://jsfiddle.net/podbarron/nj04xms5/

```
$(function(){
$('#carousel-indicators').on('click', 'li', function(){

});
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: seems like you have added a wrong call there, its 'else if()' you have mentioned 'if else'

Comment: @ameenulla0007 thanks for the help. I tried it, but it doesn't make what I want to happen, happen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bootstrap Carousel has an event which fires on/after each slide transition. You should be able to use this.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/nj04xms5/7/

The js inside the event is very basic but just to give you an idea.

`e.relatedTarget` will get you the current slide you are on if you wanted to get information from it (i.e. the ID)

```
$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {
      if(e.relatedTarget.id == 'firstSlide'){
          $("#landingContainer").css('background-color', 'orange');
      } else if(e.relatedTarget.id == 'secondSlide'){
          $("#landingContainer").css('background-color', 'green');
      }
})
```

Comment: Way better than my answer @haxtbh . Any advice on how to learn what's in the bootstrap JavaScript?

Comment: This info is freely available on the bootstrap documentation. - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-events

Comment: Gotcha @haxtbh. Thanks for that. Does the e in e.relatedTarget stand for the event?

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap fires [events on carousel transitions](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-events), which is the first way you could improve this. IMHO the second big improvement would be to avoid a verbose if/else statement and define the target color on each slide, like I've done in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vt9tg6v1/)

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('.carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(event) {
        color = $(event.relatedTarget).attr('data-new-color');
        if (color) {
            $('#landingContainer').css('background-color', color)
        }
    })
});
```

**sample carousel element**

```
<div id="secondSlide" class="item" data-new-color="blue">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/1080x400/0011ff/000" alt="...">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I intend to make it background-image instead. Would this still work. Let's say if I put data-new-image="..." ?

Comment: personally I've never set background-image via `$().css()` but I think it'd work just the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
var randomColors    = ["green", "red", "white"];
var clrI    = 0;
$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {
    $(this).css('background-color', randomColors[clrI]);
    clrI++;
    if(clrI>=randomColors.length) {
        clrI    = 0;
    }
});
```

you could use array to define colors, and apply those orderly..

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('#target1').on('click', function(){
        $('#landingContainer').css('background-color', 'green');
    });
});
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if it included an explanation along with the code.